# How can I use automatic bid pricing on the Facebook Ads API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm using the Facebook Ads API to create Page Post Engagement ads. The API is in general a breeze to use but I can't seem to find a way to set automatic bid pricing or, in other words, achieve this:

[image: automatic bid pricing]

rather than this, which is what I'm getting:

[image]

My ad set is being created with `bid_type: "ABSOLUTE_OCPM"` and `bid_info: "{'ACTIONS':500}"`. `bid_info` is a required parameter so I can't leave it out. Setting it to `0` doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bid_info is required only if you set `is_autobid` to `false`, which you need to set to `true` when you create your set.

With `bid_type: "ABSOLUTE_OCPM"` and `bid_info: "{'ACTIONS':500}"` you are saying that you'd like to bid 500 units of account's currency on action, which are expressed in cents. And as you are requesting Optimized CPM, you say how much the fulfillment of a particular goal is worth to you, therefore the $5.00 USD always show up there. As per [FB Optimized CPM documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/optimizedcpm/v2.2) these values are not bids.

Comment: Wow. Had completely missed `is_autobid`. You're a legend, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to set automatic bid via API. Moreover, usually you can just use oCPM and bid the same amount used by Facebook when you create a campaign using the automatic bid. Then PowerEditor will show you that you're using automatic bid.

=== NEW FROM v2.3 ===

From version 2.3 there is the `is_autobid` field. By setting it to true Facebook will set the bid value automatically. You can read more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adset/v2.3#create

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure what you mean with «you can just use oCPM and bid the same amount used by Facebook when you create a campaign using the automatic bid». Could you please clarify?

Comment: For example, for some campaign objective (website clicks should be one of them), if you bid using oCPM and a max bid amount of 10$, it will be shown as "Automatic bid". I have no info on the precise bid amounts, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, but I have been trying several numbers and they all show up with "set the amount a post engagement is worth" rather than automatic.